# req.url for / in Connect

Tags: node.js

I have a simple `connect` server on my Node.js script and I want to use the `req.url` to detect if the user is requesting the `/` and then check if there was the right cookie on the request, if there is redirect to the dashboard, if not send the `index.html`. But what's the `req.url` when the user requests `/`?

*PS: I tried using `case "/":` but it haven't worked*

Comment: I'm not sure what you're exactly asking, but maybe this helps: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/pull/523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `req.path` instead, and the path will be `/`.